# Move list item all the way to the right upon click

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I've been dabbling with a few jQuery carousel plugins and it seems as if almost all of them are triggered by clicking on an arrow that's placed either to the left or the right of the list. I'd like to know if there is anyway to make a list item swing all the way to the left upon click of it.

```
<style>
     ul {
         list-style:none;
         height:20px;
         overflow:hidden;
     }
     li {
        float:left;
     }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

So, upon click of let's say, the fourth list item, how could I make it swing all the way to the left as if it was now the first item in the list.

Comment: a fiddle would help a lot!

Comment: what do you mean? Is all you want to do is move the fourth <li> to the top so it now becomes <li>fourth</li><li>first</li>etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is unclear, but I thought I would tackle it based on what I think you're asking. I've put together this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svk3by3m/) that demonstrates (a bit too literally, probably) what you've asked. I set `position: relative` on the `li` and a class of `last` on the fourth `li`.

```
$(".last").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({right: "125px"});
  $("li:nth-child(-n +3)").animate({left: "50px"});
});
```